# Reverse Class to template item - Create Visual Studio Item Templates based on an existing class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, t4

I am aware that Visual Studio has T4 templates and code generation, most answers on SO reference creating classes from template, but not the reverse process of templates from a class.

My question is about reversing the process, namely I have a framework that made extensive use of custom recipes from .NET 2.0.

**Q - How to create item/class templates from/based   on *existing class***

I have explored options of refactoring etc, but I am seeking a way to quickly create multiple templates.

Comment: I doubt this is possible.  How would the T4-template-generator know what options should be configurable in the template?  Or what the source data is supposed to look like?  Code generation is an operation that is relatively simple to do forwards, but extremely difficult to do backwards.

Comment: @BJMyers I agree it would be hard to do and would need the developer to _prefix which are code blocks vs. text blocks_ which is fine by me, I was checking to see if one exists. I remember this is how Reverse POCO started

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **Reflection**... a quick starter on reflection

You can start by either loading or deriving an assembly

- example of loading an assembly

  ```
  Assembly assembly = new Assembly().LoadFrom([file path])
  // Use LoadFile to load multiple assemblies with the same identity
  ```
- example of deriving an assembly

  ```
  Type t = typeof([simple type or class]);
  Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);
  ```
- example from current assembly

  ```
  Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  ```

From the assembly you can either get Types or Modules

- example for types

  ```
  Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
  ```
- example for modules

  ```
  Module[] modules = assembly.GetModules()
  ```

From Types or Modules you can load Properties or Methods

- example for properties

  ```
  PropertyInfo[] methods = myType.GetProperties();
  ```
- example for methods

  ```
  MethodInfo[] methods = myType.GetMethods();
  ```

There's a lot more to reflection than this...